# How should i organize my code in Electron?

Tags: electron

I am currently developing a desktop app using Electron and i'm trying to figure the best practices of how to organize the code.

In particular, from what i understood reading the Electron documentation, every Electron app is composed by a main process (that corresponds to my `main.js` script) that creates `BrowserWindow` instances, each one running a render process. Renderer processes cannot access directly to many Electron libraries, and should make IPC calls to the main process to do so.

So, this means that my `main.js` will be a super long script containing a lot of different functions, each one binded via IPC to a different element in the web page? Is there a better way to organize the code? In particular, is there a way to make the code more "modular" and avoid a wall text in the `main.js`?

Also, how this affects the possibility of using Angular? Is an architecture that requires IPC inter-communication between processes still compatible with the modular architecture of Angular?

Comment: You can use Angular to build up your GUI, there's no problem with that. For system calls, you might need IPC but otherwise I'd expect most of your code will be business logic which doesn't need to be in the renderer process.

Comment: so, for instance, let's consider a button that performs a HttpRequest when clicked. The function makeHttpRequest() should be in the main.js (since only the main process can access the electron net library), while all the button logic should be in a specific angular component. 
The question is: does is still make sense to build a component (that should be isolated by definition) that requires to inter-communicate with an external script?

Comment: For web requests I use node-fetch which works from the renderer process, but nothing stops you from accessing the net package via IPC. In general I prefer to structure the app within the renderer process and reserve the main one for setup and system stuff, and using IPC when needed. There's also the `remote` package you can use, but as I understand it will be deprecated.